# Visual Studio: Customizing content of Test Results window column "error message"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

I am using TDD for one of my projects. Currently there are 90 tests defined, but only 70 are actually implemented, the rest are just throwing `NotImplementedEcxception` instances.

My problem: In the VS "Test Results" window I cannot distinguish implemented but erroneous tests from yet-to-implement tests at a glance, the error message column only shows "Test method *xyz* threw exception". You have to open the popup and call "View test result details" to see the ... details.

Is there a possibility to influence how this error Message column is filled? The exceptions thrown via Assert class are already handled otherwise, these you can distinguish swiftly. I would like to have similar handling for `NotImplementedExceptions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If asserts already provide the behavior you want then why try to reinvent existing functionality. You could replace the not implemented exception with an `Assert.Fail` and include a `not implemented` message.

```
Assert.Fail("Not Implemented");
```

Comment: Yes, would be a workaround (i already go the same way using a descendant of AssertFailedException). However, it would be nice to have it more elegant. From a semantics point of view, throwing NotImplementedExceptions is absolutely correct.

Comment: Trying to understand you last comment. Does that mean you created you own implementation of NotImplementedException that derives from AssertFailedException?

Comment: My current workaround is having a descendant "TestNotImplementedException" that derives from AssertFailedException. But i don't like to tell all developers "Use this instead of the common NotImplementedException when dealing with unit tests", because it´s just unintuitive.

Comment: Now I understand. The thing is that the test framework is built to look for the assert failed exception. short of trying to rewrite the framework yourself the current workaround you implemented is the way to go. IMHO `TestNotImplementedException` is still intuitive as the test has not been implemented as yet which is specific to the domain under which the exception was created for.

Comment: Of course, the name is okay, but you have to know about it´s existence. It´s just another "best practise" thing for developers that must be learned, documented, communicated and followed, making a complex working place even more complex (although that single lesson is not really hard to learn). I try to avoid those situations where ever i can.

Comment: Understood. Then the answer would be that it is not possible to influence how this error Message column is filled without forking and modifying the testing tools to satisfy your desired behavior.